# from tkinter import * showing SyntaxError when used inside function

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

Here I am using `from tkinter import *` inside a function and when I am running the code it is showing me a `SyntaxError`.

[image]

[image]

Please tell me how I can use from `tkinter import *` inside a function.

Comment: To avoid answering an XY problem - why are you importing inside a function in the first place? It is general convention to import at the module level so I don't see why you can't just move all the imports out.

Comment: You can't.  If you must do an `import` inside a function at all (which is not commonly needed), you have to import the module, and then use references such as `tkinter.whatever` to refer to objects from that module.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `import` statements to the beginning of the file, at the top. You are also importing `tkinter` twice.